# Spring LDAP 3.1 Custom User Mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm developing an application with Spring Security and Spring LDAP.
This is part of my spring-security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}"
            user-search-base="OU=UK,OU=Domain Objects,dc=test,dc=test1"
            group-search-filter="member={0}"
            group-search-base="OU=_Groups,OU=UK,OU=Domain Objects,dc=test,dc=test1"
            group-role-attribute="cn"
            role-prefix="ROLE_">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<ldap-server url="ldap://host:389/"
                      manager-dn="managerUser"
                      manager-password="ManagerPassword" />
```

Now I need to do some logic on a user attribute. I was wondering if there is a way to get that attribute during the login phase or I need to do a search on LDAP everytime I need that attribute.

Looking online now I'm a bit confused because I found online many ways to get custom attributes: extending the ContextMapper in the DAO or the AbstractContextMapper or extending LdapUserDetailsMapper.

Could you help me to find the correct solution? I think the best way would be to have an object where I can put the attribute I need during the login phase instead of querying the LDAP everytime I need that attribute.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. What I can tell you is that once you're authenticated via LDAP spring security caches the user details so you won't need to make a call to LDAP with every subsequent request.

This means that any subsequent methods called after the user is logged in can get the user details like so:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
UserDetails ldapUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Or if you prefer you can cast it to a custom class you've created as long as you implement UserDetails.

```
public class MyUser implements UserDetails {
.....
}
```

Does this help at all?